# For $x \ll y$, what is the maximum value of $x$ for which it holds true?

Tags: terminology, mathematical-physics

For $x \ll y$, what is the maximum value of $x$ for which it holds true?

I don't expect there to be a definitive answer but I am more so just curious what the general consensus on that is. I usually take $\frac{x}{y} ≤ 0.05$ to be the limit but recently I found a solution to a problem where $\frac{x}{y} = 0.103$ was taken to satisfy $\frac{x}{y} \ll 1$.

Comment: Formatting tip: write `\ll` for $\ll$.

Comment: It really depends on context, that is why the $\ll$ notation exists.  If there were a single formal definition that worked every time, we wouldn't need a new symbol, we'd just write $x <\frac y{10}$ (or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the problem at hand and especially on how accurate you need the solution to be.  Often when we say $x \ll y$ we will keep terms proportional to $\frac xy$ but ignore those proportional to $\left( \frac xy \right)^2$.  You need the ignored terms not to change the answer too much.

Comment: And the important point here is lurking in those final words: “not… too much” is a pragmatic difference, not a mathematical one.